# How do you insert a "reference" value into firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm trying to insert a document into a collection. I want the document to have a attribute of type `reference` to insert into the collection. But every time I insert into the collection, it comes out as a string or an object. How can I programmatically insert a `reference` typed value?

[image]

---

It's definitely possible to do it in the UI:

[image]

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Probably the simplest solution is to set the value of a reference key to a `doc(collection/doc_key)` because a `DocumentReference` is needed.

Example code:

```
post = {
  content: "content...",
  title: "impressive title",
  user: db.doc('users/' + user_key),
};

db.collection('posts').add(post)
```

Comment: Great tip. I didn't understand this answer until I realized that Firestore recognizes the reference and applies it automatically. I had thought this suggestion was saying to duplicate the data, I was way off!

Comment: great answer thank you for setting me on the right track.

Comment: It only worked after I removed `.ref` from `db.doc('users/' + user_key).ref` since `db.doc()` itself returns a `DocumentReference`.

Comment: how can we find the `user_key`?

Comment: Hi, wanted to use reference in my project; how can I use this in python?

Answer (score 14):

I was trying to figure this out today and the solution I came to was to use the `.doc()` to create a doc reference

```
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("applications")
    .add({
      property: firebase.firestore().doc(`/properties/${propertyId}`),
      ...
    })
```

This will store a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) type on the `property` field so when reading the data you will be able to access the document as so

```
  firebase.firestore()
    .collection("applications")
    .doc(applicationId)
    .get()
    .then((application) => {
      application.data().property.get().then((property) => { ... })
    })
```

Comment: is that property field is DocumentReference or String in model?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me though. I still get the error `ERROR FirebaseError: Function addDoc() called with invalid data` and if I just set the string it stores, meaning that this object/line of code causes this error. I tried adding `.ref` to cast it to a DocumentReference but now it doesn't seem to execute at all.

Answer (score 5):

This is the model class to store in firestore.

```
import { AngularFirestore, DocumentReference } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class FlightLeg {
  date: string;
  type: string;

  fromRef: DocumentReference; // AYT Airport object's KEY in Firestore
  toRef: DocumentReference;   // IST  {key:"IST", name:"Istanbul Ataturk Airport" }
}
```

I need to store FlightLeg object with reference value. In order to do this:

```
export class FlightRequestComponent {

  constructor(private srvc:FlightReqService, private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  addFlightLeg() {
    const flightLeg = {
      date: this.flightDate.toLocaleString(),
      type: this.flightRevenue,
      fromRef: this.db.doc('/IATACodeList/' + this.flightFrom).ref,
      toRef: this.db.doc('/IATACodeList/' + this.flightTo).ref,
    } as FlightLeg
    .
    ..
    this.srvc.saveRequest(flightLeg);
  }
```

The service which can save the object with referenced to another object into firestore:

```
export class FlightReqService {
   .
   ..
   ...
  saveRequest(request: FlightRequest) {
    this.db.collection(this.collRequest)
           .add(req).then(ref => {
              console.log("Saved object: ", ref)
           })
   .
   ..
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: ".ref" worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The value of the field must be of type [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference).  It looks like you're putting some other object in there that has a property called `id` that's a string.

Comment: Do I have to implement all those fields and functions?

Comment: When working with the Firestore JavaScript SDK, you naturally work with those objects.  Whatever AngularFire does must be wrapping that object.  You'll have to get a hold of the underlying DocumentReference.

Comment: Thanks! I just set the value to the DocumentReference that was returned form a query: https://i.imgur.com/MIY5HFU.png

Comment: @AskYous : that is a useful image. it should be working up into the queston. (with text not an image)

Comment: @DougStevenson, I now need to perform a `where` query on a field that's of type `reference`. Is that possible? If it's complicated, I can make another stackoverflow question.

Comment: If you have a followup question that's different than the first, you should definitely ask it separately.

Comment: You can import DocumentReference like this:
    import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
    
    export interface Message {
        text: string;
        userReference: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
    }

Answer (score 0):

It seems there may have been a recent update that has made the above answers outdated now. Funnily enough, the solution is even easier now. They've removed the .ref option, but the ref is automatically gotten now.

So you can just do:

```
const member = this3.$Firestore.doc('users/' + user2.user.uid);
this3.$Firestore.collection('teams').doc(this3.teamName).set({
  name: this3.teamName,
  members: [member],
});
```

Where member is the doc reference, simple as that. (Ignore the this3 lol.)