# Firestore (Angularfire) "merge" or reference one document in another

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I have a usecase where I have a document DI in collection A with some fields. And when all the necessary fields are filled and the document is saved, I need to create a document DV in collection B.

That document DV needs to take fields from document DI, but it also has another fields.

The problem is that I need some sort of link, not just a copy of the fields. When I change the fields which are common for both of the documents, I need to see the change in both of them.

Is firestore able to do this? Or do I have to do it myself by checking for changes and updating both of them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore, on its own, won't automatically mirror fields between two documents.

However, you have at least 3 options:

- You could manually mirror the data -- when you write to one document, write to both.  You'll want to use [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) (or transactions) to make sure they land atomically, though.
- You could use a [cloud function firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to automatically mirror the data (with some delay, as well as additional costs for the writes, storage, and function calls -- but of course you won't have to read multiple documents to access the data).  Note that ordering is not guaranteed for the triggers, however.
- You could store a reference to the second document in a field in the first (e.g. a [reference field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types)) to point you at the second document.  You would still need to do a second read to access that reference, however.  See more in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310245/3399890).

Comment: This answer pretty much covers it.  You could also make the document ids the same in each collection to make life easier for yourself.  Not sure if you can do that with random ones though.